# How do I code my Applicative stateful computation?

Tags: haskell

Lets say I have a [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Traversable.html) datum containing a handful of association pairs `(Index, Fruit)`:

```
type Index = Int
data Fruit = Apple | Orange | Tomato

defaultFruit = Tomato

convertFruits :: (Traversable t) => t (Index, Fruit) -> Int -> [Fruit]
convertFruits input n = undefined
```

`convertFruits` is supposed to return a list of length `n` filled with `Tomato`s, except for all places where the `input` contained an association pair with a matching index — in which case the matching `Fruit` from `input` is placed at the matching index.

Examples of expected output:

```
convertFruits [] 4 = [Tomato, Tomato, Tomato, Tomato]
convertFruits [(2, Apple)] = [Tomato, Apple, Tomato, Tomato]
convertFruits [(1, Orange), (3, Orange), (4, Apple)] = \
    [Orange, Tomato, Orange, Apple]
```

---

How can I define such a function? Can I code a pure approach *efficiently*, avoiding O(n²)?

I see that there's `traverse` which takes `Applicative` actions, and `Applicative` looks a lot like `Monad`. But in contrast to good ol' `Monad`, I'm not really acquainted to `Applicative`, practically speaking. Any help?

Comment: just to make sure I understand - the output for `convertFruits [(2,Apple),(1,Orange),(2,Orange)] 4` should be `[Tomato,Orange,Orange,Tomato]` ?

Comment: Could you please show some example input and output of what you want from this function, it is not very clear right now.

Comment: @CarstenKönig, that's left unspecified/not important; in my case there's a runtime guarantee that index-value pairs will have unique indices. So your behavior is fine (any is).

Comment: @bheklilr, yeah, sorry, my bad. I'll give example in a minute.

Comment: If you don't return a `t` any way, you don't need `Traversable`: `Foldable` should be enough. Or do you want `t (Index, Fruit) -> Int -> t Fruit`? Seeing your examples, both seem wrong, why don't you just use `Map Index Fruit -> Int -> [Fruit]`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yeah, but `Foldable` traversal also works in `Applicative` context. I'd like to try that out anyway (and avoid both `runStateT` and `foldr`-code with explicit state tuples, yuck).

Comment: @ulidtko: `input` is guaranteed to be sorted in the traversal?

Comment: @Zeta, no. Not sorted at all.

Comment: @ulidtko: In this case you can't avoid O(n log n).

Comment: @zeta, huh? I get O(n) easily with an imperative stateful algorithm.

Comment: @ulidtko: Care to share that algorithm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60237/discussion-between-ulidtko-and-zeta).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `Traversable` in this scenario, since your result is a list. `Foldable` is good enough. Lets forget even that for a second. How would `convertFruits` look like if you would stick only to lists?

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import           Data.Vector ((//))

-- O(n + length input)
convertFruitsList :: [(Index, Fruit)] -> Int -> [Fruit]
convertFruitsList input n = V.toList $ V.replicate n Tomato // input'
  where input' = map (\(ix, f) -> (ix - 1, f)) input
        -- Vector is 0-indexed, so we need to adjust the indices
```

Now, how could one do the same for `Foldable t (Index, Fruit) -> Int -> [Fruit]`? That's also simple:

```
import Data.Foldable (toList, Foldable)

convertFruits :: Foldable t => t (Index, Fruit) -> Int -> [Fruit]
convertFruits input n = convertFruitsList (toList input) n
```

As you can see, it's not necessary to use `traverse` or `Applicative` in this scenario at all.

Comment: Actually, great idea. However, my `Traversable` is a FingerTree from the `fingertree` package (with a couple of custom monoids), and it has no `toList`! Bummer.

Comment: @ulidtko: Every `Foldable` has [`toList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList). And every `Traversable` is a `Foldable`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect use for the `ST` monad:

```
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array(elems)
import Data.Traversable

type Index = Int
data Fruit = Apple | Orange | Tomato
    deriving Show

defaultFruit = Tomato

convertFruits :: (Traversable t) => t (Index, Fruit) -> Int -> [Fruit]
convertFruits input n = elems $ runSTArray $ do 
    a <- newArray (1,n) defaultFruit
    _ <- for input $ uncurry (writeArray a)
    return a
```

`ST` lets you use mutability to get your efficient O(n) algorithm within a pure computation.